# How to add button in same row as headline?

Tags: html

My goal is simple: having a label on the left, and a download button on the right.
They should result in the same line, preferably aligned in the middle of the headline.

But at least the following is not working:

```
        <div>
            <h1 style="display:inline-block">My Label left</h1>

            <div style="float:right">
                <a href="/export" target="_blank">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"> Download</span>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbav4mhe/

Answer (score 1):

Add a class or `id` to the outer/wrapper div and then set some css to it, like the below code shows. (Also, you don't need that `float: right` if using the CSS I provided)

```css
#wrapperDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperDiv">
  <h1>My Label left</h1>

  <div>
    <a href="/export" target="_blank">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"> Download</span>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```